# How does order (ecommerce) pixel tracking work?

Tags: php, json, web-services

Im thinking about building an application on our website to track order places through our website and pass them over to another application via JSON feed. Just wondering if anyone knows of any tutorials to do this type of thing? Im guessing this would be done using a webservice or JSON => database feed. Any advice?

Comment: The question is too vague. The good formed question contains at least half of an answer. This one doesn't

Comment: This is something you could have found out yourself with a little search effort. [StackOverflow is not a research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172661) - we're not a substitute for doing basic research. We're also [not a link farm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/172661); posting questions here about where else to go isn't what we do. Voting to close as "not a real question".

Comment: Ok - thanks. Was just looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject of your question is about pixel tracking, so I think you may be asking about a [web bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug).  Attach a cookie to the bug, and you get lots of fun data.  Beware of modern browsers' security settings.

JSON is just a format for transferring or storing data.  You don't need that for web bugs.